# Why isn't this a list?

Tags: list, recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml, typeerror

Forgive my newness to OCaml, but I have a very simple function where I'm returning the intersection of two lists, but only when the element is in both lists at the same time. On the third line, I'm told "This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 'a list", but isn't that a list I'm outputting?

```
 let rec intersection (l1 : 'a list) (l2 : 'a list) : 'a list = match l1,l2 with
  | [],[] -> []             (* empty lists *)
  | [h1::t1], [h2::t2] ->   (* non-empty lists *)
      if h1 = h2          (* if both elements are the same *)
        then h1 :: intersection(t1,t2)   (* include in intersection response *)
        else intersection(t1, t2)        (* else ignore it and check the remaining elements *)
```

Comment: All arms must return the same type. In the `else` expression it seems to me `intersection(t1, t2)` can return just an `'a`. Posting the entirety of the function would be more helpful.

Comment: `intersection(t1, t2)` calls `intersection` with a tuple `(t1, t2)`. It should be called `intersection t1 t2`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything with the type error. Still get 

This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
         'a list
       The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list

Comment: If I change the patterns as I suggest, I do not get the same error. There is an error, but it isn't the same error. In fact, it's the error pointed out by @PieOhPah above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a :: b` is a list whose head is `a` and whose tail is `b`. So then the expression `[a :: b]` is a list of lists. Very likely your patterns should be `h1 :: t1` and `h2 :: t2`.

It would be much easier to help if you post the entire function as @PieOhPah points out.

**Update**

There are at least two errors in your code. If I compile your code as given above I see this:

```
File "a1.ml", line 5, characters 13-15:
Error: This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type
     'a list
     The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list
```

If I change your pattern from `[h1 :: t1], [h2 :: t2]` to `h1 :: t1, h2 :: t2`, I see this:

```
File "a2.ml", line 5, characters 31-38:
Error: This expression has type 'b * 'c
   but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

This second error happens because your recursive calls to `intersection` are passing tuples `intersection (a, b)`. But `intersection` is defined in curried form, i.e., it takes separate arguments `intersection a b`. This is what @PieOhPah is pointing out.

If I make both changes I don't see any further type errors. There are other errors, but they aren't type errors.

Comment: added the whole function. Doesn't OCaml allow for lists to be defined inside brackets without it being a list of lists?

Comment: There are two notations for lists: `[a; b]` and `a :: b :: []`. You have combined these notations, so you get a list of lists.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield answer is clear enough. The cons (`::`) already constructs a list. That means you should match `(h1::t1, h2::t2)` without square brackets (parentheses only for clarity).

Comment: this doesn't change anything tho. I'm still getting the exact same type errors at h1 in line 5, regardless of how I format the lists.

Comment: Yes, there is a *different* error if you make the change proposed by @PieOhPah and me. See PieOhPah's comment on your original post.

Comment: ahhh I understand now. So a list has to be defined as _::_ without brackets or else its a list OF a list, and calling a function with two variables must be separated or else it's a tuple! Alright! Syntax is killing me but thank you both very much!